# Can/should we change the standard message posted when a late answer by a new user doesn't answer the question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The "late answer" review queue is triggered by a "new user's answer to an old question."

When I use that queue, I always follow the link to see the context of the answer. Many of the answers from that queue have what looks like a standard message, which is:

> This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - From Review-name of reviewer.  *("From review" has a link to the review queue. I don't want to post a specific one.*)

- The "Ask Question" link opens a page for asking a question. In my opinion, this is helpful and easy to understand.
- The "add a bounty" link goes to the [Set Bounty Privileges](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) page in the Help Center. It explains how a bounty works, and states that 75 rep is needed to use that privilege. The new user has either 1 rep, or a few more if the answer has been upvoted. They most likely don't understand our system, and even if they read that page, they still have to be around for a while to amass 75 rep. In my opinion, this isn't the best way to teach a new user, and might even confuse them. I also don't think many people who are incorrectly answering a question are likely to then put a bounty on it. Also, a number of these "not an answer to the question" posts end up, rightly, getting deleted.
- "From Review" links to the page in the review queue from whence it came. The instructions there are for the reviewers, and, again, would be confusing to a new user. It takes our users 350 rep to even use those queues.

Is this a standard message? It's not only moderators who use it, so maybe its not mod-managed, or an SE system-wide thing. Can we change it? Alternatively, can we create a new one which is more likely to teach a new user? I'd be happy to work with the community to design a new version. I think it should definitely start with a welcome statement.

If we can't change it, would it be a good idea for reviewers to just skip it altogether? If we have time, we could leave a quick explanation, including a link to the Ask a Question page? Some people already do that, and I think it's more personal, and leaves the person less intimidated than leading them to things they either don't understand, can't do, or both.

We're an extremely welcoming site (better than a number of others). We're patient, and have a strong focus on helping people understand our features, and feeling free to ask how we can help them with things they don't understand. It's one of the reasons I'm proud to be a part of this community. I'm referring only to this message.

Do people agree with me? My first attempt at an answer on SE (a different site) was deleted without any offer of help at all. That may be coloring my point of view.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for an edit?

Comment: The "does not really answer the question" canned comment is standard across all SE sites. I've seen some grumbling about it on MSE (e.g. meta.stackexchange.com/q/…) but not sure if there's much support for changing it.

Comment: Hint: Even if you work the review queue, you can still add a comment to add details.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with you that the message should be changed. When I had time I have modified a few of these messages that were generated by my review, but for the most part of reviews I have kept the original text. I have noticed that a few of the modified ones had convinced the user to expand their answer, while the automated ones were completely ignored. Sometimes I choose not to review anything because I don't have the time to explain my actions.